# HDFS concat operation: Does it lead to increased seek time?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, concatenation

I was trying to go through how HDFS implements the concat operation and drilled down to the following piece of [code](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-hdfs/2.2.0/org/apache/hadoop/hdfs/server/namenode/FSDirectory.java#FSDirectory.unprotectedConcat%28java.lang.String%2Cjava.lang.String%5B%5D%2Clong%29).

From this implementation it seems to me that concat is only a meta operation on Inode of the target file and the actual blocks are not moved. I was thinking if this would lead to fragmentation + increased seek time as different blocks would be on different locations on the disk (considering a magnetic disk). Is this assumption correct? If yes can we avoid this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few experiments I found the answer to my own question. After very frequent file concat operations (around 1k per minute) the data node started complaining about too many blocks in around a day which lead me to believe that this indeed does lead to fragmentation and an increased number of blocks on disk. Solution I used is to write a separate job that concatenates (and compresses in my case) these files into a single splittable archive (note gzip is not splittable!).